# Log4net: no logs written when application running in Win8 without "as administrator"

Tags: log4net

Our application uses log4net to write some logs to the local disk with RollingFileAppender. It runs well in local developing machines until we test it with remote desktop connection in virtual machines.

After install it in Win8, we have to run it as administrator to let it write logs. Even if we login the remote win8 with a local administrator account of the win8.

Things are different in win7. The application always writes logs even if we login the remote win7 with a domain user. Maybe you are interested in the config file, let me put it here:

```
<log4net>
<appender name="RollingFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
  <file value="c:\mylogfile.txt"/>
  <appendToFile value="true"/>
  <rollingStyle value="Size"/>
  <maxSizeRollBackups value="5"/>
  <maximumFileSize value="10MB"/>
  <staticLogFileName value="true"/>
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %level %logger - %message%newline%exception"/>
  </layout>
</appender>
<root>
  <level value="Debug"/>
  <appender-ref ref="RollingFileAppender"/>
</root>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your user does not have permissions to write to c:\mylogfile.txt. Make a directory c:\temp and try to log to c:\temp\mylogfile.txt

```
<log4net>
<appender name="RollingFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
  <file value="c:\temp\mylogfile.txt"/>
  <appendToFile value="true"/>
  <rollingStyle value="Size"/>
  <maxSizeRollBackups value="5"/>
  <maximumFileSize value="10MB"/>
  <staticLogFileName value="true"/>
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %level %logger - %message%newline%exception"/>
  </layout>
</appender>
<root>
  <level value="Debug"/>
  <appender-ref ref="RollingFileAppender"/>
</root>
```

Comment: Thank yo very much for your quick reply. What you pointed out is actually right. However, the config file is a initial config and we can update it during runtime. Finally it turned out that I made a mistake: I tried to update and save the config file under installation path where a non-admin user has no write access right. The config file is not correctly saved and no logs written where I want.